# Is FAA approval required in order to fly an RNAV SID/STAR for a private aircraft operated under FAR Part 91?

Tags: far-91, sid-star, faa-approval

I know that under FAR Part 135, specific approval is required for an RNAV SID/STAR (given via an OpSpec), but what about Part 91?  Does the aircraft/pilot have to be approved, and if so how is the approval obtained?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best answer I can give is **generally, no.**

In relatively few cases – for aircraft **operated under Part 91 Subpart K**, which applies to fractional ownership like Netjets – the operator must possess an [Mspec](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N%208900.176.pdf), which would be applied for at the local FSDO. I'm not sure what that process looks like, but [the FAA's Commercial Operations Branch has some good information on that front](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/afs/afs800/afs820/part91k_oper/).

**For all other Part 91 operations** the aircraft simply needs to be appropriately equipped.